# choose data from excel based on date

Tags: excel

I have an [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) sheet with data like:

```
2000-01-01  2000    1
2000-01-02  2000    2
2000-01-03  2000    3
2000-01-04  2000    4
2000-01-05  2000    5
2000-01-06  2000    6
2000-01-07  2000    7
2000-01-08  2000    8
2000-01-09  2000    9
```

ordered by date till:

```
2017-04-22  2017    1
2017-04-23  2017    2
2017-04-24  2017    3
2017-04-25  2017    4
2017-04-26  2017    5
2017-04-27  2017    6
2017-04-28  2017    7
2017-04-29  2017    8
2017-04-30  2017    9
```

the question is, how to Filter data based on dates, knowing that I need to view months 1,2,3 and 4 only..

- I tried Filter -> Data Filters -> between
  but it gives me first year (2000) only..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can filter by specific values in your list.  First, add (or change) a column to add a formula calculating the month from the date, like:

```
=Month(A2)
```

[image: How to filter by specific values]

If you're only getting a choice of some of the values, then you haven't selected the entire range of data.  The easiest way to select the entire range is to only select the **column headers** (after adding some) and highlight them before choosing `Filter`.

Another way to filter by the month column:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Why not choose Filter -> Date Filters -> Custom Filter, then you can review the specific dates by limiting 'is before' and 'is after'.

Or try Filter -> Date Filters -> 'All Dates in the Period'

Comment: **All Dates in the Period** is a great idea, but it can't be customized, I can only choose quarter 1 , which is filter dates between 01-01 til 31-03 and I need to view till 30-04..